# Why does my app engine task block a page refresh?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, asynchronous, transactions

I'm learning about App Engine task queues. My application has tasks that process documents. Each task will take approximately 5-10 mins to complete. My aim is to monitor the progress of each task via a web page.

As a test, I adapted the [push queue tutorial code](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push) with a simple loop (See below). When the  'analyser page' form is submitted a new 'transaction loop' task is launched.

I was surprised that the asynchronous 'transaction loop' prevented the refresh of the 'analyser page' until the task was complete.

I have two questions:

1. Why does the asynchronous task stop the page refresh?

   My naive view of the implementation behind tasks is that each task is a scheduled thread or process and the 'transaction loop' thread would block during the datastore io, letting the 'analyser page' thread refresh. (This is out of interest as our final code will be significantly different from this test)
2. Using the datastore/memcache to record task progress seems fairly heavy weight, especially with regards to write quotas-- is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,

Brian

---

Tested on dev server 1.6:

```
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

class Counter(db.Model):
     count = db.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)

class Analyser(webapp.RequestHandler):
    # Analyser Page  -- Page refresh (get) only completes after task is called
    def get(self):

        self.response.write("<html> <body>")

        # My first  guess was that calling counter.put() blocked the Counter.all() 
        # call to the datastore. 
        # However commenting the following code had the same effect.

        # self.response.write("Counters:<br>")
        # counters = Counter.all()
        # for counter in counters:
        #   self.response.write(str(counter.count) + "<br>")

        self.response.write("<form action=\"/api/analyse\" method=\"post\"> \
                            Key: <input type=\"text\" name=\"key\" /><br /> \
                            <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" />  \
                        </form>")

        self.response.write("</body> </html>")

def post(self):
    key = self.request.get('key')
    # Add the task to the default queue.
    taskqueue.add(url='/analyse_worker', params={'key': key})
    self.response.write("Added task with key:" + key)

class AnalyserWorker(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self): # should run at most 1/s
        key = self.request.get('key')

    def txn():
        counter = Counter.get_by_key_name(key)
        if counter is None:
            counter = Counter(key_name=key, count=1)
        else:
            counter.count += 1
        counter.put()

    # Transaction loop
    for i in range(0,200):
        db.run_in_transaction(txn)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dev appserver is single threaded, which is why your refresh page is blocked until the task completes.

Comment: Hi Stuart, thanks for the reply. That makes sense. Although this feature makes it tricky to develop a task intensive app. Do you have any suggestions on how to develop this? I can of course simulate (stub?) the tasks in development but it would be nice if there was a standard way. Can you run an app engine virtual machine?